# Hide dired buffers from IBuffer list?

Tags: buffers, dired, ibuffer, buffer-list

I have a dired workflow that I like. From a file-visiting buffer, I'll use `dired-jump` to pop up to the containing directory. Dired renders the directory in a new buffer with the cursor on the file-entry I came from. Another `dired-jump` puts me in the parent directory with the cursor on the subdirectory I was in. This makes it easy to drill back down with a series of Return keypresses.

The downside is that dired generates a lot of buffers in order to build such a "breadcrumb" trail. I mitigate this somewhat by reusing buffers on my way down, using `dired-find-alternate-file`. But I still end up with multiple dired buffers littering the buffer list, so I'd like to find an easy way to toggle hiding dired buffers in IBuffer.

As an example, with a file-tree like,

```
~        
├── A    
└── B    
    ├── x
    └── y
```

and starting from the file `~/B/y`, running `dired-jump` results in (using `|` to represent the cursor position):

```
buffer contents  buffer list
---------------  -----------
~/B:             ~/B/
.                ~/B/y
..
x
y|
```

Another `dired-jump`:

```
buffer contents  buffer list
---------------  -----------
~:               ~/
.                ~/B/
..               ~/B/y
A
B|
```

Then `find-alternate-file`:

```
buffer contents  buffer list
---------------  -----------
~/B:             ~/B/
.                ~/B/y
..
x
y|
```

And another `find-alternate-file` puts me back into file **y**, with only `~/B/y` in my buffer list.

Comment: The question is unclear to me. Please provide a recipe to repro the problem (e.g. how reusing Dired buffers interferes with whatever). Is this a question about improving some Dired behavior, or is it, as the title says, just a question about telling Ibuffer to hide some buffers? If the latter, what does it really have to do with Dired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all you want is to hide `*dired*` buffers from ibuffer, just add this to your `.emacs` :-

`(add-to-list 'ibuffer-never-show-predicates "^\\*dired")`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a custom filter group, like so:

```el
/ m dired-mode RET                      ;Filter by dired-mode
/ !                                     ;Negate filter
/ s non-dired RET                       ;Save filter as "non-dired"

(add-hook 'ibuffer-mode-hook
          (lambda nil (ibuffer-add-saved-filters "non-dired")))
```

Note, that you can negate the filter as desired, in case you need to view the dired buffers.

Comment: Oh cool! I'll try this, and take a further look at IBuffer filters.